# Summing up answers in the top answer

Tags: discussion, answers

I often meet top/accepted answers that in the end states something like "Others suggest to do ..." and includes solutions from other answers/comments.

**Is this a good practice?**

I understand that they are trying to make one post that will cover all the information so you don't have to look else where. On the other hand, I always look for other solutions from other answers. Isn't this kind of stealing others "ideas"/reputation?

Comment: Not so sure you quoted that correctly, not many google hits for "others suggest" and most of them are followed by "however" or "but" :)  I think what you saw are questions from the first two years of SO.  List questions were very common back then.  Pretty hard to deal with, everybody and his brother has an answer.  A common strategy to deal with it was to community-wiki the Q+A and aggregate the answers.  Happily such questions are firmly off-topic today.

Comment: I made a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/459349/search-for-answers-containing-others-suggest) for it and I can confirm Hans Passant's observation. In many cases the meaning is actually "my solution is not like others suggested" - which is perfectly fine.

Comment: That was just an example, the actual phrase I've seen last was different, unfortunately I'm not able to find the Q&A anymore.

Answer (score 18):

I think that it depends on the post and answers.

If you think you can add better details and clearer explanation, go for it (you can/should gently mention the person you're quoting). But keep in mind that not every post should have all details summed up in one place; I came across many posts having many answers, that each one adds another detail - and that's fine, users should be able to navigate between answers and conclude the minimal things required to build a complete solution.

Comment: It's also an option to improve an existing answer as long as you don't change the original meaning. (This always means avoiding adding code.)

Answer (score 10):

An answer that just collates other answers is effectively either plagiarism (if unattributed) or downright unethical (if attributed). Feel completely free to downvote these.

An answer that collates answers given as comments is [a symptom of a wider problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247446/155739). Where people have created this scenario, posting such an answer is probably the best way to fix it. Sometimes people make these answers *community wiki* so that they don't get any rep from it. Honestly, though, it would be better if people didn't abuse the Q&A model in the first place.

An answer that builds on "hints and tips" sadly given as comments, adding cohesion and perhaps some additional reasoning, is an answer in its own right and worthy of continued existence. If someone complains that the answer "steals" their "hints and tips", then point out that they had the opportunity to write a proper answer, and they declined to take it.

Comment: I don't think either of cases covered in this answer fall under "that *in the end* states something like..."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I don't understand. Are you suggesting that I need to add a paragraph to cover the case where the OP waits until lots of other answers have been posted, steals their content, then travels back in time and posts the same answers just after the question was written?

Comment: I've added my view as answer. I think there are valid cases to enumerate other approaches. I read question as "there is valid answer plus info on other answers" indeed there are less desirable cases you've covered.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: From the question: _"they are trying to make one post that will cover all the information so you don't have to look else where"_. Good answer though.

Answer (score 8):

It is perfectly fine to link to *alternative* solutions after providing complete answer first (Link + half a sentence describing approach).

Copying (even with attribution) other answers is bad practice. There definitely no need to catalog *all* existing answers.

One case may be an exception when top answer has significantly higher quality then the rest - as long as alternative answers rewritten to match quality of main answer (and include attribution).

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the situation. In some cases it may be an attempt to convert Q&A into a Wikipedia style encyclopedia kind of thing. Just imagine every answer would contain "others suggest that...". It would probably result in a lot of clutter.

We don't need one answer to rule them all. It is usually expected that people read more than just the top voted answer and find out about alternatives naturally.

Answers can be sorted by votes and the first couple of high voted answers cover most of the topic. And the sorting is done by user votes. No need for anyone to help us in the sorting or recommend other answers. The votes are sufficient recommendation.

In other situations a direct comparison to other answers is included, e.g. there is actual content existing related to the other answers. This would for example be the case if other answers only partially solve the problem and a combined, improved solution is found but needs to attribute the previous work. Then it's fine (with the right attribution).

But if they are pure recommendations I would see them as rather unhelpful. In any case proper attribution must be given. See: [Attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) which means linking and mentioning the authors name at the least.